# Python - Luigi - Copy to Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, luigi

I want to define a Luigi task that will create a table in a Postgres db in AWS. I have tried different imports like:

```
import luigi.contrib.postgres.CopyToTable
from luigi.contrib.postgres import CopyToTable
import luigi.contrib.postgres
from luigi.contrib import postgres
import luigi.postgres ( i thing this is depreceated)
```

And I receive a different errors but always similar, like:

```
AttributeError: module 'luigi.contrib' has no attribute 'postgres'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'luigi.contrib.postgres'
```

Does anyone knows what is the problem? My task is the next:

```
class InsertToRDS(luigi.contrib.postgres.CopyToTable):

    def requires(self):
        return ReShape()

    host = ""
    database = ""
    user = ""
    password = ""  # ;)
    table = "extropy"

    columns = [("author", "TEXT"),
               ("file_id", "TEXT"),
               ("year.month_x", "DATE"),
               ("subject", "TEXT"),
               ("subject", "TEXT"),
               ("file_timestamp", "TEXT"),
               ("mail_content", "TEXT"),
               ("next_message", "TEXT"),
               ("prev_message", "TEXT"),
               ("year.month_y", "DATE"),]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: think*(line 5 - first block of code)

Answer (score 3):

```
from luigi.contrib.postgres import CopyToTable
```

is the right syntax and then you can follow up with...

```
class InsertToRDS(CopyToTable):
```

are you sure luigi installed properly? At the command line check the output of:

```
pip show luigi
```

if the right version shows up, run `python` at the command line and try the first import line again. If it works there, the way you are running your program is borked.